# Does "whenever / whether" equals to iff?

Tags: turing-machines

I encountered a question that goes like this:

```
M is a TM that accepts w^r whenever it accepts w
```

which of the following does it mean?
 M accepts **w^r**  **<->**  M accepts w
 M accepts **w^r** **->**  M accepts w
 M accepts w **->**  M accepts **w^r**

same question for whether please.. thank you :)

Comment: "$M$ is a TM that accepts $w^r$ whether it accepts $w$" does not make much sense

Comment: Whenever means *if* in that context.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez So you mean the third option is the correct one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already commented, "whether" has no business here.

Now an idea: when you want to clear out for yourself the meaning of some more or less obscure phrase, try to find out every day words to substitute and understand a little better what's going on.

In this case, let us substitute for example "*M accepts* $\;w^r\;$" with "*I am alive*" , and "*M accepts* $\;w\;$" with "*I talk*" , so the given phrase is

"I am alive whenever I talk" , and now ask yourself what's the closest meaning to reality: does it mean

== I am alive iff I talk == , or

== If I am alive then I talk == , or

== If I talk then I am alive ==.

The first two fall at once when you think of mute people, and the third one is really true. You can try different words/phrases to put instead.

This is **not** proof that the actual sense is what Mariano commented, and it could perfectly well be that the author simply mispoke (this happens quite a few times with scientists/authors in general who have not much training in logics. Mathematicians usually go wrong in these matters less than others) , but I think it could be a good instrument for you (and everybody) to check a particular meaning in many cases.